# Dnsmasq changing from working .dev to .local

Tags: macos, dnsmasq, macos-high-sierra

I have configured dnsmasq on mac os high sierra with *.dev domains to point to 127.0.0.1 and it all worked great. But now I want to change my localhost domains from *.dev to *.local, so I changed it in dnsmasq.confg file and created a resolver 'local' for it. but dnsmasq doesn't seem to referesh the domains. And now it doesn't work with any of them .dev or .local.

Here are my configurations :

My /usr/local/etc/dnsmasq.conf file has 
'address=/.local/127.0.0.1'

My Resolver , /etc/resolver/local has 
"nameserver 127.0.0.1"

/Library/LaunchDaemons/homebrew.mxcl.dnsmasq.plist service is also loaded.

I don't know what should I do next so that domain.dev becomes domain.local now ?

If I do dig domain.local , this is what I get

[image]

Comment: Hey @sohail, it seems like we can't use `.local` when setting up dnsmasq; I've been trying to set this up as well; using `.test` or `.localhost` works, but not `.local`. There could be some special config for it, but I can't seem to find it anywhere. EDIT: I found this link about why we can't use `.local`: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/155745/how-do-i-configure-yosemite-to-be-able-to-resolve-dns-ending-in-local

Comment: Thanks Yusuf. that is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change `.local` to `.test`, and it should work.

Comment: For people who downvoted, its right. .local won't work. I have changed mine to .lan , you can change any to whatever you like except .local and .dev